# Using hyperbolic geometry to derive Lorentz transforms

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, special-relativity

I want to know how to derive the below Lorentz transformation formula using hyperbolic geometry

$$ct' =  ct \cosh\phi - x \sinh\phi$$
$$x' = x \cosh\phi - ct \sinh\phi$$

Here is a spacetime diagram

[image]

From the diagram, the line OH is $ct$ and the line OF is $x$. I think $x$ equals $AC\cosh\phi + OB\sinh\phi$ and $ct$ equals $CE\cosh\phi + OD\sinh\phi$.

It doesn't look right to me. I am not sure why the correct formula use $-\sinh$ not $\sinh$. Also I can't tell which line (OA or OB) equals to $ct'$ and which line (OE or OD) equals to $x'$.

I need someone to show me how to geometrically derive the correct Lorentz transform formulas.

Comment: Haven't you found something on the Web ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I can't find any easy-to-understand visual explanations on deriving LTs with hyperbolic geometry

Comment: As currently formulated your question does not really make sense. Hyperbolic geometry has many models: the upper half space model; the Beltrami-Klein model; the hyperboloid model; and more. A particular format of the isometries of hyperbolic geometry depends very strongly on which model you have chosen.